# Get Parent Custom Taxonomy Term and Color Div background

Tags: terms

I am currently displaying posts from a CPT.  Each has a taxonomy term from a parent. I would like to create a function that would color the background of a div of particular parent terms.

Here is my set up:

Lets call this Cars:

> Domestic
>    --Dodge
>    --Ford
>    --Chrysler
>
> Import
>    --Honda
>    --Toyota
>    --Kia
>
> European
>    --BMW
>    --Benz

The parent is Domestic, Import, European.

My posts displays as follows:

> Ford
>   Post Title
>   Post Content
>
> Toyota
>   Post Title
>  
>   Post Content

Etc.

My goal is to color the DIV that the child term is held in.  For example:

```
<div class="car_type">Ford</div> (background green)
Post Title<br> 
Post Content<br>

<div class="car_type">Toyota</div> (background red)
Post Title<br> 
Post Content<br>
```

I am trying to construct the following:

```
if (parent_term == 'domestic'){
.car_type{
background-color:green;
}
}

if (parent_term == 'import'){
.car_type{
background-color: red;
}
}
```

So far I have checked out get_terms.  Any help pointing me in the right direction would be amazing.

Thank you, I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to adjust the markup to suit your specific needs, but the easiest solution would use [a `post_class` filter](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class#Add_Classes_By_Filters) on the [`post_class()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class) template tag, to output appropriate classes.

For example, in your template, you need to call `post_class()`, such as:

```
<div <?php post_class(); ?>>
<div class="car_type">Ford</div> (background green)
Post Title<br> 
Post Content<br>
</div>
```

Then, filter `post_class`, using your term:

```
function wpse123081_add_post_classes( $classes, $class, $postid ) {

    // Custom Tax
    if ( 'carsCPT' == get_post_type( $postid ) ) {
        foreach ( (array) get_the_terms( $postid, 'carsTax' ) as $term ) {
            if ( empty( $term->slug ) )
                continue;
            $classes[] = 'term-' . sanitize_html_class( $term->slug, $term->term_id );
        }
    }
}
add_filter( 'post_class', 'wpse123081_add_post_classes', 10, 3 );
```

This will turn this:

```
<div <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

...into this:

```
<div class="term-carTaxTerm">
```

(along with other classes, of course)

And you can target your CSS accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for this, I believe this is what I was looking for.  Quick question, I am using a plugin to display my loop (lazy i know :) and it doesn't accept php code.  If I would like to make this into a shortcode, will it still work?

So it will be something like:

<div [my_shorts]>

Thanks!

Comment: That's really a tough question to answer without knowing the Plugin code or how it does what it does. That might work, or you could create your own Custom Page Template.

Comment: I am using the Views plugin from wp-types.  It can take short codes and execute them within the plugin.  If I take what you wrote and turn it into short code, so I use something like <div [my_shorts]> so it replaces [my_shorts] with <?php post_class(); ?>. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Modified as shortcode:

```
function my_color_heading( $postid ) { // Custom Tax
    if ( 'jobs' == get_post_type( $postid ) ) {
        foreach ( (array) get_the_terms( $postid, 'department' ) as $term ) {
            if ( empty( $term->slug ) )
                continue;
            $classes[] = 'term-' . sanitize_html_class( $term->parent, $term->term_id );
     $classList = implode(" ",$classes);
     return "class= {$classList}";

        }

    }

}
add_shortcode('heading_colors','my_color_heading');
```

Thanks!!